# ANOVA Repeated Measures: Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases

Tags: anova

I need to run a repeated measures anova model for this database. But I get this error: "Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :   0 (non-NA) cases"

```
ANOVARep1 <- anova_test(data = Data2, dv = NEE, wid = ID, within = Treatment)
```

I have already checked that my database does not have NAs and that "Treatment" is a factor with 4 levels.

```
head(Data2)
      Plot Treatment Sampling.Date Trampling           NEE           ER         Met1         Met2      Methane WTL ID
107 Alto 1      High    20/07/2022         1  5.082730e-06 4.067484e-06 3.563489e-08 2.886338e-08 3.224914e-08 6.5  1
108 Alto 1       Low    20/07/2022         1  1.769624e-06 2.338062e-06 4.461730e-08 3.315017e-08 3.888374e-08 6.5  2
109 Alto 1   Control    20/07/2022         1 -2.670837e-06 2.676352e-06 4.320588e-08 3.949032e-08 4.134810e-08 6.5  3
110 Alto 1    Medium    20/07/2022         1  3.397547e-06 4.913275e-06 4.130892e-08 4.090383e-08 4.110637e-08 6.5  4
111 Alto 3   Control    20/07/2022         1 -4.804427e-06 3.236301e-06 5.922239e-08 5.433923e-08 5.678081e-08 6.7  5
112 Alto 3      High    20/07/2022         1  3.612795e-06 4.811508e-06 9.300005e-08 9.639110e-08 9.469558e-08 6.7  6
```